# How to select Markers from Google map change some values is DB for selected markers

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi im having an req that i need select some markers and call some action to change DB value

for Egg. if im displaying 4 markers on map and i want to change some value of 2 markers in DB

now i'm able to display markers but im not getting how to do above task

can any one please help me 
let me know if u want much more info

below is my code

```
<div id="LangLat" style="display: none;">
    <s:property value="content" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var loc = document.getElementById("LangLat").innerHTML;

    y = loc.replace(new RegExp("&quot;", "g"), "\"");
    locations = JSON.parse(y);
    var ini_loc = new String(locations[1]);
    var lonLati = ini_loc.split(",");
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom : 13,
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(lonLati[1], lonLati[0]),  
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1],
                    locations[i][0]),
            map : map,
            icon : locations[i][2]

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',
                (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
    }
</script>
```

above code display's all markers now i want to bring up an check box to select some  markers  and an submit action which changes some value in DB for selected marker

Thanks in advance 
Manju

Answer (score 0):

You can use `click event` on markers for this.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    //Your custom code handler
```

});

Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple

Comment: thanks for your replay im aware abt click event how can i bring check box to select markers

Comment: Share some code in a fiddle, without it no one can help.